# Populating the data in array

Tags: java, arrays

How to populate the array without iterating it with known size and value?

Example: If I want to create an array of size 5 with values 1. I don't want to iterate with size 5 and use add method. Is there any other way?

Comment: 'Array of size 5 with values 1' can u explain a bit more?

Comment: I am not sure what data structure you are talking about when you say "use add method". Are you referring to a list rather than an array?

Comment: @suraj:its always better to specify your requirements and use case to get better inputs from community

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating a string array with variables:

```
String foo = getFoo();
String bar = getBar();
String[] myStringArray = { foo, bar};
```

Instantiating a string with literals:

```
String[] myStringArray = {"foo", "bar"};
```

Filling an existing array with some value:

```
Arrays.fill(myStringArray, "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = new int[5];
Arrays.fill(array, 1);
```

This should work.

Comment: I do not know what he was asking, as arrays do not have an add method :D

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can achieve that by following

```
int[] array = new int[5];
Arrays.fill(array, 0);
```

additionally you can check following link

[Array Fill](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
Arrays.fill(arr,1);
```